# Android Clearing all EditText Fields with Clear Button

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

How do I clear all the `EditText` fields in a layout with a `Clear Button`.  I have a registration Activity that has about 10 different `EditTexts`.  I know I could go and grab a reference to each specifically and then `set.Text("")`;  But I am looking for a more dynamic elegant way.  Possibly grab the `Layout` and loop through all the items in there looking for `EditText` types and then setting those to `""`.  Not sure how to do that though and tried searching on the web for it but no luck.  Any sample code?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The answer by @Pixie is great but I would like to make it much better.

This method works fine only if all the EditText are in a single(one) layout but when there are bunch of nested layouts this code doesn't deal with them.

After scratching my head a while I've made following solution:

```
private void clearForm(ViewGroup group) {       
    for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
        View view = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText)view).setText("");
        }

        if(view instanceof ViewGroup && (((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount() > 0))
            clearForm((ViewGroup)view);
    }
}
```

To use this method just call this in following fashion:

```
clearForm((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.sign_up));
```

Where you can replace your R.id.sign_up with the id of root layout of your XML file.

I hope this would help many people as like me.

:)

Comment: This code works great, thanks again!  If I could I would upvote this 20 times!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works brilliantly .. Cheers (y)

Comment: Just added this code again to another program I am writing.  This should be made into a standard in Android.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 31):

You can iterate through all children in a view group and clear all the `EditText` fields:

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.your_group);
for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
    View view = group.getChildAt(i);
    if (view instanceof EditText) {
        ((EditText)view).setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for saving me some time! I was going to use a different approach but this one is much much better!

Comment: Can this ViewGroup be applied on Any Layout like i have a Main Linerlayout so if i do this it will set the text of all my edittext in the activity empty?

Comment: @Harinder I don't understand what you mean. `ViewGroup` is a base class for compound widgets (widgets that can contain other widgets). So you can apply this method for clearing all `EditText` widgets in `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Kindly correct this line as casting is important:
`ViewGroup group = findViewById(R.id.your_group);'
 to `ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.your_group);`

Comment: This code does not apply to EditText views that are in a nested layout, and will only work for those that are in the root view

Comment: Yeah, but you can iterate through all sub-groups recursively.

Comment: Is this optimized?? Thanks. :D

Comment: @KarenAnne, what do you mean?

Comment: @Michael like isn't that too expensive to use, looping through the views?

Comment: @KarenAnne It depends on how often you're going to do it and how many child views are in the view. Usually, such code cannot make your application work slower, because this code is executed very rarely. But if you think this code reduces UI performance, you should profile the application and if the bottleneck is in this code, optimize it. As an optimization, you can cache all 'EditText's within the view and iterate only them.

Answer (score 8):

Use `editText.getText().clear();`

Comment: Did you read the question its not just one field it is many fields

Answer (score 1):

after onclick of any action do below step

```
 ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.yoursXmlId)).setText("");
```

or Clear all EditText fields by iterating all childrens:

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.your_group);
for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
View view = group.getChildAt(i);
if (view instanceof EditText) {
    ((EditText)view).setText("");
}
}
```

or use simple below step :

```
editText.getText().clear();
```

Might be helpful.

Comment: Did you read the question its not just one field it is many fields

Comment: @JPM yup read and updated according to the questions and accepted answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.Type this in your function of button-

```
finish();
startActivity(this,YourCurrentActivity.class);
```

As Simple as that.
Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've done this.

```
public static void resetForm(ViewGroup group) {
    for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
        View view = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText) view).getText().clear();
        }

        if (view instanceof RadioGroup) {
            ((RadioButton)((RadioGroup) view).getChildAt(0)).setChecked(true);
        }

        if (view instanceof Spinner) {
            ((Spinner) view).setSelection(0);
        }

        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && (((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount() > 0))
            resetForm((ViewGroup) view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this for nested LinearLayout to clear EditTexts and RadioButtons

//method clear
    private void clear(ViewGroup group)
    {
        for(int i=0,count=group.getChildCount();i

```
        if(view instanceof  LinearLayout)
        {
            clear((ViewGroup) view);
        }
         else if(view instanceof EditText)
        {
            ((EditText) view).getText().clear();
        }
        if (view instanceof  RadioButton)
        {
            ((RadioButton) view).setChecked(false);
        }
    }//end for
}//end method clear
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this...it works for me:

```
mClearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mEditName.getText().clear();
            mEditSummary.getText().clear();
            mEditPrice.getText().clear();
            mEditQuantitiy.getText().clear();

        }
    });
```

this way you have one fat button that clears all the fields for you once

Answer (score 0):

I created a reset button and write a reset onclick method as follow:

```
    public void reset(View View){

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);

    }
```

It works for me and also it works without addflags part. But I would like to know whether it is a good approach or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
   // Update answer

private void clearEditTextGroup(ViewGroup group){


    for(int i=0 ; i< group.getChildCount(); i++){
    View view = group.getChildAt(i);
    if(view instanceof EditText){

    // use one of clear code
    }

     if(view instanceof ViewGroup && (((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount() > 0))
            clearEditTextGroup((ViewGroup)view);

    }


   }
```

use one of this code to clear your edittext

```
edittext.getText().clear();
```

or

```
edittext.setText(null);
```

or

```
edittext.setText("");
```

Comment: Did you read the question its not just one field it is many fields

Answer (score -2):

use
`editText.getText().clear();`

or setText as Empty using this below code
`editText.setText(");`

Comment: Hey did you read the question?  Your answer only does one field.