# "Too many synthetic parameters..." error in Eclipse. How do i circumvent/solve it?

Tags: android, view, onclick

I have a very rare question and cannot find any information on the internet about this issue!

I have a button in an android app, and the code to this button is driving me crazy. Apparently there are some imitations as to how many "if" sentences you can make in your button routine?

Here are some snippits (BTW, etX = EditText):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (et1.getText().length()+et2.getText().length()==10) {keys++; oneStr=oneStr+et1.getText().toString()+" "+et2.getText().toString()+" ";}
    if (et3.getText().length()+et4.getText().length()==10) {keys++; oneStr=oneStr+et3.getText().toString()+" "+et4.getText().toString()+" ";}
    if (et5.getText().length()+et6.getText().length()==10) {keys++; oneStr=oneStr+et5.getText().toString()+" "+et6.getText().toString()+" ";}
```

This goes on until:

```
    if (et293.getText().length()+et294.getText().length()==10) {keys++; oneStr=oneStr+et293.getText().toString()+" "+et294.getText().toString()+" ";}
    if (et295.getText().length()+et296.getText().length()==10) {keys++; oneStr=oneStr+et295.getText().toString()+" "+et296.getText().toString()+" ";}
```

So all in all 148 "if" sentences!

The exact eclipse error text is:
**"Too many synthetic parameters, emulated parameter val$et253 is exceeding the limit of 255 words eligible for method parameters**"

If I delete all the "if" sentences after and including:

```
if (et253.getText().length()+et254.getText().length()==10) {keys++; oneStr=oneStr+et253.getText().toString()+" "+et254.getText().toString()+" ";}
```

The error is no longer there, and the program works for the many if sentences that are already there.  So obviously something is wrong, but i do not understand the error?

So when I go from the 148 "if" to 125 "if" sentences the app can compile!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you want to write this code? Why not use a array. Ther MUST be another solution than this horrible code duplication.

Comment: The code could probably be created much smarter instead of this code duplication. I have alot of this for this particular activity, but simply do not know how to deal with it. So I made a python script that could create all this duplication for me.
I have looked into this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740708/android-clearing-all-edittext-fields-with-clear-button
because I later on fill some of the EditTexts with data, but that particular code snippet in my program is apparantly not a problem!

Comment: you seriously have ~255 edittexts on the same screen?

Comment: njzk2 yeah unfortuneately ~296 EditTexts :( And also ~296 ImageView :(
So eclipse is very slow for this particular activity when I edit it ;(
The thing regarding putting objects such as ImageViews and EditTexts in arrays are new to new to me, and something I did not know was possible!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, when Java is implementing closures (and I use the term loosely here), it cheats and creates a copy to the referenced variable in the form of a synthetic parameter. From the error, it looks like there is an upper limit to the number of variables that can be pulled in to your anonymous inner class using this mechanism.

More than likely, if you converted `etnnn` variables to an array `et[nnn]`, the problem would go away, because you'd need to pull in only one variable instead of hundreds.

One reference that is probably related to your problem is from [Java VM Specification, Section 4.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#88659):

> The number of method parameters is limited to 255 by the definition of
>   a method descriptor (§4.3.3), where the limit includes one unit for
>   this in the case of instance or interface method invocations. Note
>   that a method descriptor is defined in terms of a notion of method
>   parameter length in which a parameter of type long or double
>   contributes two units to the length, so parameters of these types
>   further reduce the limit.

Comment: Thank you so much for you explanation. I made it work using loops throughout the app :)
Actually the .apk size decreased also around 200kb which is very nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

See if it compiles when performing 148 actions in a loop. If that works, USE A LOOP for doing a similar action 148 times...

Comment: In my onCreate I have:

    final EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText001);
    ...    
    final EditText et296=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText296); 

So am I supposed to to put these EditTexts in an array in the onCreate method, and pass the array to the button onclicklistener?

Comment: Yes. et[0] = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText001); ... Even better you can make them in a loop too.

Comment: Thank you so much for you explanation. I made it work using a loop :)