# Clearing multiple EditText fields with Clear Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have looked at other questions regarding this problem but the solutions don't work for me. I have a number of edittext fields on a page and want to be able to reset them with one button press. I implemented the solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740708/android-clearing-all-edittext-fields-with-clear-button) but I have nested linear layouts and it only clears the edittext that is a direct child of the main container. How can I get it to find all of the edittext fields or will I have to reference each one?

My xml file structure is as follows:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/MainParent">
        <LinearLayout>
            TextView
            EditText
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            TextView
            EditText
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            TextView
            EditText
        </LinearLayout>
        EditText
        <LinearLayout>
            Button1
            Button2
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Snippet from Java File:

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.MainParent);
       for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
           View view = group.getChildAt(i);
               if (view instanceof EditText) {
                   ((EditText)view).setText("");
       }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not interested in referencing each EditText specifically, I'd make a recursive function to handle the hierarchy.

```
public void clearAll(ViewGroup root) {
    for (int i = 0, j = root.getChildCount(); i < j, i++) {
        View view = root.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            clearAll((ViewGroup) view);
            continue;
        }
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText) view).setText("");
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just call:

```
clearAll((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.MainParent));
```

Answer (score 1):

After onClick of any action do below step :

```
EditText firstEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yoursXmlId);
firstEditText.setText("");
```

Comment: I will have to repeat this code for each edittext field though. Is there a way to avoid doing this?

Comment: You have to declare editText only once in onCreate() Method and make one function in set blank text in all the edit text and call the function whenever it requires

Comment: I was under the impression you didn't want to reference each EditText specifically.

Comment: @nEx.Software you are correct. I've tried various implementations of this solution and I have to reference each EditText. This answer is not correct and I've unmarked it. Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout group = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.MainParent);
       for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i)
         {
           View view = group.getChildAt(i);
               if (view instanceof EditText) {
                   ((EditText)view).setText("");
       }
```

Comment: Similar suggestion to Chirag Raval's answer below I see where I was going wrong. Thank you

Comment: this doesn't work it still only clears the edittext that is a direct child of the MainParent