# Menu option to clear all <EditText>

Tags: java, android

I am designing an app in Android Studio, but I am having trouble creating a clear option in the menu of my app.

Can someone show me how to add a menu option that will clear all the `<EditText>` items in my app I am creating?

Comment: Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740708/android-clearing-all-edittext-fields-with-clear-button

Comment: From clear you mean clear the edittext's text ? And in the whole application ?

Comment: how are you creating menu in your app, post the code you tried

Comment: ******MainActivity.java*******

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code and change the id of "your_group" with your main layout id.

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.your_group);
for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
View view = group.getChildAt(i);
if (view instanceof EditText) {
    ((EditText)view).setText("");//here it will be clear all the EditText field
}
}
```

Please let me know if have any doubts.

Comment: //MainActivity.java//