# Reset code for EditText and TextView for android

Tags: android

I'm new in programming. I did a simple android app which ask user to put 2 numbers, do calculations, display the answer by clicking calculate button. Now I'm trying to set up reset button to clear all the fields. Checked for the solution on stack overflow, but still cannot figure out how to do it. This is my code:

```
 public void calculate(View view)
 {

    EditText number1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1ID);
    EditText number2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2ID);

    Double num1Value = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());
    Double num2Value = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());

    Double resultValue = num1Value - num2Value;
    TextView resultDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultID);

    resultDisplay.setText(Double.toString(resultValue));
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You use the setText method, passing empty string: `.setText("")`

Comment: Hi @nick. I've found [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5816949) which seems quite interesting as well. Might serve as a reference for others. In essence, IF you have only EditText in a single layout, you can use this method to reset them all. **Edit**: I understand you are new in programming, I wouldn't expect you to understand what's going on, but again, it may serve as a reference for others.

Comment: you are right, it looks quite complicated to me, hopefully I will be able to wrap my head around this solution sooner than later. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add button resetButton to layout

```
Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset); 
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            number1.setText("");
            number2.setText("");
            resultDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Have a method like this

```
public void resetTextViews() {
      number1.setText("");
      number2.setText("");
      resultDisplay.setText("");
}
```

Then just set an on click listener on your button that calls that method.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method in EditText to clear the data. If you want to clear the data you have to set

```
.setText("");
```

In android documentation itself there is no option to reset the field.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want reset your edittext ?

```
private void resetNumbersFields() {
  number1.setText("");
  number2.setText("");
  resultDisplay.setText("");
  // if you want you can add setHint to add hint to your EditText when your field is empty
}
```

I hope that help you

Answer (score 2):

Exact code for your program.

```
public void calculate(View view) {

  EditText number1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1ID);
  EditText number2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2ID);
  Button B_reset=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bReset);
  // create a button on your Layout for Reset as "bReset"

  Double num1Value = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());
  Double num2Value = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());

  Double resultValue = num1Value - num2Value;
  TextView resultDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultID);

  resultDisplay.setText(Double.toString(resultValue));


//reset code 
  B_reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
      number1.setText(""); // reset the EditText number1
      number2.setText(""); // reset the EditText number2
      resultDisplay.setText(""); // reset the Textview resultDisplay
      }
  });

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`edittext1.setText(StringUtility.EMPTY);`. It will help.

Answer (score 1):

OnClick of Reset Button set the setText of EditText to Empty Strings.
You can follow the below link it is useful for beginners 
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/android-tutorial/